# iOS App distributed from Airwatch MDM not launching

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mdm, airwatch

iOS App is been downloaded in air-watch MDM through volume purchase program and distributed to managed devices.

When user opens the app. it just goes away. It mainly happening in iPads.

Comment: Do you have other apps in your VPP? If yes, no issue with the others?

Comment: Yeah others apps have no issue

Comment: It could be related to blacklisting apps with AirWatch, have you checked that?

Comment: yeah checked it. but it is not the case

Comment: Does that app need to use some native app like Camera? If yes, maybe it is that app which is deactivated by one configuration.

Comment: When you said mainly on iPads, is it on every iPads you have?